# Build a Java reminder for a web project

Tags: java, timer

I have a requirement for a web project to build a reminder that display a message for the input date and time. I don't want to use any plugins or jar files. I came up with the code and there is an error in `timer.schedule(task,date);`

I'm also new to java and don't know if this is the right approach.

Code:

```
public String reminder(Model model, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ParseException
{

    String myDate = "2012-06-09 17:43:20";

    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(myDate);

    TimerTask task = YoTimes(model);
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(task,date);

    return "/view";
}

private TimerTask YoTimes(Model model) 
{
    model.addAttribute("timerMsg", "Yo Timer");
    return null;
}
```

**EDIT**

Stacktrace:

```
ERROR:java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at java.util.Timer.sched(Unknown Source) 
    at java.util.Timer.schedule(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What is the error? Can you post the stacktrace? As a sidenote, your `YoTimes` method returns `null`. Is that intentional? Could it be that the error is a `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Why are you casting the Date object returned by the `DateFormat#parse(...)` method?

Comment: ERROR:java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.util.Timer.sched(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Timer.schedule(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 2):

```
private TimerTask YoTimes(Model model) 
{
    model.addAttribute("timerMsg", "Yo Timer");
    return null; // ************
}
```

Please look at what you're returning here!

No surprise then that this will cause a NPE. Perhaps you want to return an actual TimerTask object. ;-)

So instead create and return your TimerTask:

```
private TimerTask YoTimes(final Model model) 
{
    model.addAttribute("timerMsg", "Yo Timer");
    return new TimerTask() {
       public void run() {
          // whatever code you want called by the timer
       }
    };
}
```

Comment: I just started learning java. So, what should I return? Can you please edit my code? It will be great.. Thanks

Comment: @maxi: you should return an actual TimerTask object. Please check out the [TimerTask API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) to see what this will require. But most importantly, since TimerTask implements the Runnable interface, your TimerTask object will absolutely need to be a run method override.

Comment: Model is for printing in the JSP..
import org.springframework.ui.Model;

Comment: @maxi: see edit regarding how to create and return a TimerTask object

Comment: The error is fixed. But seems like my logic is wrong. I have put the - model.addAttribute("timerMsg", "Yo Timer"); inside the run() but it doesn't work.

Comment: @maxi: you're assuming that we have a clue as to how the rest of your program works including code not shown or described. Consider telling more including what exactly is supposed to happen when the timer activates the TimerTask.

Comment: I want to show a message(eg. 'Its Maxi Birthday today!') in the jsp when the time is up. Its just to show a reminder message.

Answer (score 2):

Your `YoTimes` method returns `null`. It should return an instance of `java.util.TimerTask`, so that you can pass it to `Timer#schedule(TimerTask, Date)`.

The edited `yoTimes` method (note that as a best practice / convention, Java methods should start with a lowercase character):

```
private TimerTask yoTimes(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("timerMsg", "Yo Timer");
    return new MyTimerTask();
}
```

The newly created `MyTimerTask` class:

```
public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        // Whatever the task should be
    }
}
```

Comment: @maxi Have a look at the [TimerTask API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) and at this [example](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html) (first result on Google, there are gazillions of them). Basically, create a `MyTimerTask` class that extends `TimerTask` and has a `run()` method that actually does the task you want to carry out, and make the `YoTimes` method return `new MyTimerTask()`.

Comment: The issue got fixed. What I wanted was to print the -- model.addAttribute("timerMsg", "Yo Timer"); in the jsp. I included this inside the run() but it didn't work. I did set the time.